# Check if I can execute some sql-command

Tags: .net, t-sql, sql-server-2008, ado

I'm using ADO .NET and MS SQL Server 2008.

I have a connection object to a server and a command:

```
SqlConnection conn = /* my connection*/;
string cmd = "some_sql_command";
```

I want to check if SQL Server *can* execute `cmd`. I don't want to execute `cmd`, but I want to know If SQL Server can execute it.

`cmd` can be any *single* SQL statement, it's not a procedure, transaction or multiple commands etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can always start a transaction, execute the command and then *roll back* the transaction so that no changes are made to the database.

Another option is to use [ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.executenonquery.aspx) method, which, when passed [ParseOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.executiontypes.aspx) flag, only parses the command and does not do anything else.

Comment: Just as a note, Query Analyzer / Management Studio don't truly obey SET PARSEONLY ON - they still execute the statement.  You also need to use SET NOEXEC ON and/or SET FMTONLY ON, however in doing so you lose the binding capability of the parser, so it won't warn you about invalid object or column names.